# Using TDBLoader in JENA

Tags: jena, semantic-web, ontology, tdbloader

I'm trying to learn how to use TDBLoader using this example I found:

https://github.com/ijdickinson/jena-tdb-ont-example

However, when trying to run the init-demo script, I keep running into issues
https://github.com/ijdickinson/jena-tdb-ont-example/blob/master/src/main/script/init-demo

I'm using cygwin to attempt to run the script, but I keep getting please ensure $Path contains $TDBROOT/bin

I set TDBROOT= C:\Development\apache-jena-2.12.1
And my Path has "%TDBROOT\bin"

I'm really new to using command line and shell scripts, so I'm not at all familiar with how to go about debugging this.

I have my tdbloader in apache-jena-2.12.1\bin , is there a way I can check if this is even working? Or if my path is properly set?

I tried "tdbloader" and "-v tdbloader" in command line and I get "tdbloader" is not recognized...

That's not supposed to happen if my path is set correctly, right?

Comment: There is a script in <installdir>\bat\tdbloader.bat to run TDB loader on windows. This post-dates the artical you have found. If you are on Windows with cygwin, the version of java is usually windows. Manually, "java -cp "<installdir>\lib\*;" tdb.tdbloader ... should work.  Note "lib\*". <installdir> is the top directory from unpacking Apache Jena.

Comment: Hey,

Thank you for the reply! I appreciate it. So, just so I understand what I'm doing " " java -cp "<installdir>\lib*;" tdb.tdbloader "  is going to point cygwin to the tdbloader that's needed? And the .sh script should run?

Sorry if this is a stupid question, I'm new to this and trying to understand what I'm doing.

Comment: cygwin+java is a strange world.  The command line is unix-style, the Java is windows-style. Hence the command to run must be windows-like (hence use ";" and "\").  IIRC (I don't run cygwin anymore) you can run bat scripts.

Comment: Correction: -cp '<installdir>\lib\*' -- I missed a "\"  And note that cywgin command line so "\" may need escaping if you use outer double quotes.